# golang unencode string to be parsable into json

Tags: go, url-encoding

How do I get [this](http://play.golang.org/p/EQLUqzIqds) to work?

```
s, _ := url.QueryUnescape("%22%7B%5C%22sessionId%5C%22%3A%5C%225331b937-7b55-4c2d-798a-25e574a7e8af%5C%22%2C%5C%22userId%5C%22%3A2%2C%5C%22userName%5C%22%3A%5C%22datami_op%5C%22%2C%5C%22userEmail%5C%22%3A%5C%22datami_op%40example.com%5C%22%2C%5C%22userRoles%5C%22%3A%5B%5C%22operator%5C%22%5D%7D%22")
fmt.Println(s)
//s := "{\"sessionId\":\"5331b937-7b55-4c2d-798a-25e574a7e8af\",\"userId\":2,\"userName\":\"op\",\"userEmail\":\"datami_op@example.com\",\"userRoles\":[\"operator\"]}"
var i Info
err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(s), &i)
fmt.Println(i, err)
```

Comment: You have json stored in a json string. Can you fix that, or do you have to decode this value exactly as is?

Comment: I would have like to not have it, but as of now, it's what I'm getting.  I do have a brute force solution in http://play.golang.org/p/of6XgePtOu.  But I'm hoping that there is a cleaner way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either manually remove the quoting yourself, as you have in your comment, or you could unmarshal first as a json string:

```
var unquote string
err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(s), &unquote)
fmt.Println(unquote, err)

var i Info 
err = json.Unmarshal([]byte(unquote), &i)
fmt.Println(i, err)
```

Comment: Or `go doc strconv.Unquote` can be used to remove quotes (double in my case) and then feed the output to json.Unmarshal.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this does what you want: 
<kbd>[**GoPlay**](http://play.golang.org/p/7M00dQPiN9)</kbd>

Essentially you implement `unmarshalJsonJson` (clever name, I know)...
The function will unmarshal as a json string, then use that string in the Info unmarshalling.

```
func unmarshalJsonJson(inval string) (*Info, error) {
    var s string
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(inval), &s)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    info := new(Info)
    err = json.Unmarshal([]byte(s), info)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return info, nil
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
main.Info{
    SessionId:"5331b937-7b55-4c2d-798a-25e574a7e8af",
    UserId:2,
    Username:"datami_op",
    Email:"datami_op@example.com",
    Roles:[]string{"operator"},
}
```